# Can SQL Server detect deadlocks involving joins with linked databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-deadlocks

I have code with queries that look like this:

```
INSERT INTO LinkedServer.DB.dbo.Table1 (column)
SELECT something
FROM   LocalDB.dbo.Table2
WHERE  something NOT IN (SELECT column FROM LinkedServer.DB.dbo.Table1)
```

There's a lot of other code in the ecosystem that could be touching those tables.  Today, this SQL code hung for way longer than I expected it to.  If there were a deadlock between Table1 and Table2, can SQL Server detect that if it's a linked server?

Also, what if LocalDB were only calling out to LinkedServer and not locking any of its own objects?  Can it detect the deadlock if the affected objects are all on the remote server.

In this case, LocalDB is 2012 R2 and LinkedServer is 2008

Answer (score 0):

As per my  understanding deadlock between two different tables can happen only  when there is short of resource in the server level, Are you trying to understand the Deadlock between you insert and select queries . Then yes let say you are inserting some records into the table in the Linkedservers and at the same time you are selecting data in localDB using the data in Linkedservers, But since the insert is not yet completed that can cause the blocking to you sub-query  which  is trying to fetch data from the Linkedserver and pass the data to localDB select query. in this case blocking will be because of Table1 only which is of linkedserver but from our point of view it looks like table2 is being blocked by table1 but in actual that is not the scenario.  And yes off course the deadlock information will be available in the case i explained but those information will be available in the DMV's of the linkedserver.